# Difference between presentational skills and presentation skills

Tags: meaning

what is difference between these two sentences and why:
sentence 1:this course is going to teach you about **presentation skills**.
sentence 2:this course is going to teach you about **presentational skills**.

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same thing.

"presentation skills" - the word "presentation" is a noun being used as an adjective, modifying "skills".

"presentational skills" - the word "presentational" is an adjective modifying "skills".

The first choice "presentation skills" is recommended, since it's the most common. [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=presentation%20skills%2Cpresentational%20skills&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpresentation%20skills%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpresentational%20skills%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpresentation%20skills%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpresentational%20skills%3B%2Cc0) shows that it's used 10-20 times more frequently.

In a list of the most common words from Google, "presentation" is number 3068 while "presentational" is number 57675, next to demurrage, foia, and bushings.

"presentational" is so unusual that my browser has it underlined in red as a misspelling.